# limited size dates groups by interval

Tags: r

I have a data frame with dates and I would like to group dates by interval of 9 days, but the group size should be of 7 dates maximum. So if we find 9 days in the interval, the 2 last dates should roll to the next group and so on.

And the starting date of an interval can only be an existing date of the dataset.

Here is an example :

```
start_date <- as.Date("2020-04-17")
dates <- c(start_date,  
           start_date + 10:16, 
           start_date + c(17, 18, 20), 
           start_date + c(30, 39))
x <- data.frame(date = dates)

> x
         date
1  2020-04-17
2  2020-04-27
3  2020-04-28
4  2020-04-29
5  2020-04-30
6  2020-05-01
7  2020-05-02
8  2020-05-03
9  2020-05-04
10 2020-05-05
11 2020-05-07
12 2020-05-17
13 2020-05-26
```

And the exected output :

```
         date group
1  2020-04-17     1
2  2020-04-27     2
3  2020-04-28     2
4  2020-04-29     2
5  2020-04-30     2
6  2020-05-01     2
7  2020-05-02     2
8  2020-05-03     2
9  2020-05-04     3
10 2020-05-05     3
11 2020-05-07     3
12 2020-05-17     4
13 2020-05-26     4
```

I'm really stuck ony this, nothing worked from what I tried so far, any help would be really apprectiated, thank you !

Comment: so, a new interval of 9 days should start if: a: the previous date > 9 days ago, b: the previuos date was the 7th date in the previous interval?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry if it was not clear. Actually your reformulation is helping me to think about my problem differently

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you want. As you can see, the code is quite inefficient, but I can't think of the way without going sequentially.

```r
start_date <- as.Date("2020-04-17")
dates <- c(start_date,  
           start_date + 10:16, 
           start_date + c(17, 18, 20), 
           start_date + c(30, 39))
x <- data.frame(date = dates)

assign_group <- function(group_var, group_number) {
  # finding the start of the group
  start_idx <- min(which(is.na(group_var))) 
  # finding the end of the group (either group size == 7 or the dates in the range)
  end_idx <- start_idx + min(6, sum(x$date > x$date[start_idx] &
                                      x$date <= x$date[start_idx] + 9))
  # taking care of the out of range index
  end_idx <- min(end_idx, length(group_var))
  # assign group number
  group_var[start_idx:end_idx] <- group_number 
  return(group_var)
}

group <- rep(NA, nrow(x))
group_number <- 1

while(sum(is.na(group[length(group)])) > 0){
  group <- assign_group(group, group_number)
  group_number <- group_number + 1
  print(group)
}
#>  [1]  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#>  [1]  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA
#>  [1]  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3 NA NA
#>  [1] 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4

x$group <- group
x
#>          date group
#> 1  2020-04-17     1
#> 2  2020-04-27     2
#> 3  2020-04-28     2
#> 4  2020-04-29     2
#> 5  2020-04-30     2
#> 6  2020-05-01     2
#> 7  2020-05-02     2
#> 8  2020-05-03     2
#> 9  2020-05-04     3
#> 10 2020-05-05     3
#> 11 2020-05-07     3
#> 12 2020-05-17     4
#> 13 2020-05-26     4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! It's helpful to figure out another approach to my problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `Rcpp`:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
IntegerVector grpDates(IntegerVector dates, int winsize, int daysaft) {
    int sz = dates.size(), start = 0;
    IntegerVector res(sz);  

    res[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < sz; i++) {
        if ((dates[i] - dates[start] > daysaft) || (i - start + 1 > winsize)) {
            res[i] = res[i-1] + 1;
            start = i;
        } else {
            res[i] = res[i-1];
        }
    }

    return res;
}")
x$group <- grpDates(dates, 7L, 9L)
x
```

output:

```
         date group
1  2020-04-17     1
2  2020-04-27     2
3  2020-04-28     2
4  2020-04-29     2
5  2020-04-30     2
6  2020-05-01     2
7  2020-05-02     2
8  2020-05-03     2
9  2020-05-04     3
10 2020-05-05     3
11 2020-05-07     3
12 2020-05-17     4
13 2020-05-26     4
14 2020-06-03     5
15 2020-06-04     5
16 2020-06-05     5
17 2020-06-06     5
18 2020-06-07     5
19 2020-06-08     5
20 2020-06-09     5
```

data with more date rows:

```
start_date <- as.Date("2020-04-17")
dates <- c(start_date,  
    start_date + 10:16, 
    start_date + c(17, 18, 20), 
    start_date + c(30, 39),
    start_date + 47:53)
x <- data.frame(date = dates)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it looks very efficient performance-wise ! Though I don't know how to code with c++ so it will be a hard challenge for me to adapt your code. I would like to apply this operation by groups in my data frame, for example my data would be `data.frame(grp = c(rep("x", 10L), rep("y", 4L)),  date = c(seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 9L, Sys.Date(), by = 1L), Sys.Date() - 11L, Sys.Date() - 8L, Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 9L))` So I guess one option using Rcpp would be to wrap your loop into another loop looping over the groups ids, right ?

Comment: i would blend it with `data.table`. for e.g, `setDT(x)[, group := grpDates(date), grp]`

Comment: oh yes that was obvious, i feel stupid. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: No problem at all. If you look closely at the cpp code, it’s actually not that hard